# How to exclude url which matches keywords in list- web scraping(python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am stuck somewhere. I am doing google search extraction with selenium and using python.

Now i have some keywords that i enter into google search and extract data(this is what code do)

i have another negative list also which has certain keywords. Now i want to check if those keywords exist in the data extracted ,do not them append into new list. How can i do this?

below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import csv
import time
from itertools import groupby,chain
from operator import itemgetter
import sqlite3

final_data = []
def getresults():
    global final_data
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Jobs_data.db")
    conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS naukri(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, KEYWORD text, LINK text,
                            CONSTRAINT number_unique UNIQUE (KEYWORD,LINK))
                            """)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #chrome_options = Options()
    #chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    #chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome   Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
    with open("./"+"terms12.csv", "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            keywords = row[0]
            url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?num=10&q=" + keywords
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(5)
            count = 0
            links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g")[:3]
            for i in links:
                data = i.find_elements_by_class_name("iUh30")
                dm = negativelist("junk.csv")
                print(dm)
                for news in data:     
                    sublist = []
                    data = news.text
                    if dm in data:
                        continue
                    print("I am in exception")
                    sublist.append(keywords)
                    sublist.append(data)
                    print(sublist)
                    final_data.append(sublist)
                    cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO naukri VALUES (NULL,?,?)",(keywords,data))

    conn.commit()                    
    return final_data

def negativelist(file):
    sublist = []
    with open("./"+file,"r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            _data = row[0]
            sublist.append(_data)
    return sublist

def readfile(alldata, filename):
    with open ("./"+ filename, "w",encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        csvfile.writerow("")
        for i in range(0, len(alldata)):
            csvfile.writerow(alldata[i])
def main():
    getresults()
    readfile([[k, *chain.from_iterable(r for _, *r in g)] for k, g in groupby(final_data, key=itemgetter(0))], "Naukri.csv")
main()
```

error received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\projects\google_Rank_Chcker1\Naukri-links.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\projects\google_Rank_Chcker1\Naukri-links.py", line 70, in main
    getresults()
  File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\projects\google_Rank_Chcker1\Naukri-links.py", line 42, in getresults
    if dm in data:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are checking if the Data exists in the NegativeKeywords, which is not exacly the same as to say if the NegativeKeywords exist in the Data.

```
if data in dm:
    continue
```

Probably what you want is:

```
# Create a function to check if the data contains any of the negative keywords
def dataContainsNegativeKeyword(data, dm):
    for word in dm:
        if word in data:
            return true
    return false

# In the code check for that function with your kewywords and data
if dataContainsNegativeKeyword(data, dm):
    continue
```

Then weirdly you are adding to the *sublist* both the keyword and the data:

```
 sublist.append(keywords)
 sublist.append(data)
```

Maybe Here what you wanted to attain is to define *sublist* as a dictionary and then add *keywords* (Which is a bit of a missname, maybe *keyword* should be better since it's only one element as far as I can see) as the key of the dictionary and *data* as the value.

```
sublist = {}
# Rest of the code here
sublist[keywords] = data
```

An other thing you could improve from the code is that you are loading the negative keywords in each iteration:

```
dm = negativelist("junk.csv")
```

You don't actually need to do that in each iteration, just declare this at the begginig :)

Comment: I have updated my post entered error and entered new codes... I received the error 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: My bad there, dm is a list, not a string. That's why it's not working, add another loop there to go over all the dm's. I'll update the code with a sketch.